# R: My dataframe has 1 column and multiple rows, is there a way to calculate the mean for certain subsets of rows?

Tags: r, excel, for-loop, row, mean

I downloaded a data frame that is 1 column and 1000s of rows. The data frame is organized so that there is the name of the region, and below that scores corresponding to the region.

Example:
[image]

**I want to calculate the mean of the values corresponding to each region.**

So, for example:

Region 1: mean of 1,2,3,4

Region 2: mean of 1,2

And so on

I am unsure about how to write a script to do this and get an output where
I have a table that has 2 columns (Region, mean value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is independent of the character strings that mark the beginning of the groups, it only depends on them not being coercible to numeric.

First, a test data set.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("A", 1:4, "B", 1:2, "C", 1:3))
```

Now the group means.

```
y <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(df1[[1]]))
i <- is.na(y)
j <- cumsum(i)
tapply(y[!i], j[!i], mean)
#  1   2   3 
#2.5 1.5 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  Map(
    function(v) data.frame(Region = v[1, ], Mean = mean(as.numeric(v[-1, ]))),
    split(df, cumsum(grepl("Region\\s\\d+", df$x)))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
    Region Mean
1 Region 1  2.5
2 Region 2  1.5
3 Region 3  2.0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(x = c("Region 1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "Region 2", 
"1", "2", "Region 3", "1", "2", "3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-12L))
```